# Shell Scripting, remove a file without giving the entire name as a parameter

Tags: linux, shell

say we have a file named randomfile_a434534_Frank.csv

I want the user to input the  the first portion "randomfile*" as the parameter not the entire thing. how will i be able to access/say delete this particular file without specfying the entire file name

Comment: The shell will automatically expand `randomfile*` to `randomfile_a434534_Frank.csv` provided it is the only match.  This is called globing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following reprompts until a prefix matching only a single file is given. Modify to taste -- removing the loop if you want to only test once, referring instead to `$1` if you want to get the prefix from the command line, or iterating over `"${files[@]}"` in the event of multiple files matching instead of bailing/reprompting if such is your intent.

```
#!/bin/bash
# note that the above is necessary to enable features such as arrays; shells started
# with #!/bin/sh may not provide them.

while :; do
  echo "Please enter a filename prefix:" >&2
  IFS= read -r filename

  files=( "$filename"* )
  if (( ${#files[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -e "$files" ]]; then
    echo "OK; using $files" >&2
    break
  elif [[ ! -e "$files" ]] || (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "Error: No matching files found" >&2
  else
    echo "Error: More than one file matches that prefix" >&2
  fi
done

echo "Operating on file named: $files"
```

Comment: why did you put the `! -e` test before the `== 0` test?

Comment: @glennjackman, granted, the empty-list test is cheaper, but it only happens if nullglob is enabled, which doesn't strike me as a very common case.

Comment: so in the console if enter "randomfile" it should work?

Comment: @purplehaze, correct, as long as one and only one file name starting with `randomfile` exists.

Comment: oh okay, what is the purpose of using * like some of the examples I have seen?

Comment: @purplehaze, `foo*` expands to a list of all filenames starting with `foo`. Given that information, the purpose should be obvious. :)

Comment: Thanks Charles Duffy awesome answer and link!

Comment: Anyway, care must be taken about the privileges of this kind of script. See "confused deputy problem".

Comment: @Aif, if the security concerns you refer to are those named in your answer as amended, I question their legitimacy. A user could pass `/etc/passwd` just as easily as they could pass `../../../etc/passwd`; there's no security here to attempt to circumvent, and no _claim_ -- even implied -- to provide such security. The claimed arbitrary command execution vulnerability, on the other hand, is flatly nonexistent.

Comment: Agreed for the "no security claimed". I just wanted to highlight the possible messup with filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the user input to `rm "$intput"*` (or -i if you want the user to check which files are being deleted) but beware of the actual user input which could turn your script in an unintended maner.

Here is a small shell proof of concept:

```
$ touch aaJKL
$ toto=aa
$ rm -i "$toto"* # thanks Charles Duffy
rm: remove regular empty file `aaJKL'? y
```

What could happen?

- user provides ../../../path/to/sensitive/file
- <strike>user provides `./; <<nasty command>>; echo "` and executes arbitrary command</strike> as pointed out by Charles, this kind of vulnerability only happens for string substitution *before* the shell performs syntax parsing (such as when generating a string to pass to `system()`, or when `eval` is used to force an additional parsing pass).
- user uses a symbolic link to target another file

Another hint would be to prompt an inode number to the user, and ensure this inode number is legitimate.

For instance, you could do something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Choose a single file number you want to remove"
ls -i1 ./
read filenumber
if [[ $filenumber =~ ^[-+]?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        find . -inum $filenumber -delete
else
        echo "Expect integer as an input"
fi
```

Sample output:

```
$ touch sample{1,2,3,4}
$ ./so.sh 
Choose a single file number you want to remove
1614159 sample1
1614160 sample2
1614161 sample3
1614162 sample4
fds
Expect integer as an input
$ ./so.sh 
Choose a single file number you want to remove
1614159 sample1
1614160 sample2
1614161 sample3
1614162 sample4
1614159

$ ./so.sh  # notice that sample1 was deleted
Choose a single file number you want to remove
1614160 sample2
1614161 sample3
1614162 sample4
```

Comment: I'd recommend `rm -i` to allow the user to see what's being removed

Comment: `"$input"*` is safer than `$input*`, as it prevents glob expansion within the input.

Comment: If a user wants to delete a file with a literal `*` within its name, and they run `./your_script "foo*bar"`, you don't want to treat that the same as if they'd run `./your_script foo*bar` without the quotes, after all.

Comment: @glennjackman the issue here is more a malicious user IMO :) I used `rm -i` in my sample.

Comment: Some of the warnings about security in this answer are misguided: The shell doesn't conflate data and syntax unless `eval` is used, or a child shell is otherwise invoked (as by calling `ssh`). Thus, a `;` provided as data **will not** be treated as syntax and an opportunity to run a new command.

Comment: If you can show me a **tested** example (or, otherwise, something reproducible) by which `rm -i "$toto*"` -- when used with the quotes around the variable expansion -- can be used to, say, `touch /tmp/i-am-vulnerable`, I'd be very much appreciative. `./; <<nasty command>>; echo "` **does not** work.

Comment: (If you're interested, I can talk a little more about the steps involved in parsing; the short version is that syntax parsing happens long before variable expansion, so content expanded from variables cannot change syntax-level parse results).

Comment: (...that said, one security-enhancing change worth noting is that `rm -i -- "$toto"*` is somewhat safer than `rm -i "$toto"*`, as it unambiguously indicates that expansion results are positional arguments rather than further options).

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy I was mistaken. I have performed some tests, but not with the "$variable*" thing, that is right.

Comment: `"$variable*"` was a typo -- it should be `"$variable"*`; otherwise, the `*` is treated as literal rather than a glob character.

Comment: Even as amended, this is not quite right -- the quotes prevent string-splitting and glob expansion; they are *not* necessary to prevent command substitution or syntax-level parsing. I suspect that `eval` (or one of the several ways to get `eval`-equivalent behavior) was in use in the place you saw this vulnerability last.

Comment: Indeed, I'm used to code injection inside other programs, which call system() afterwards. Can't you just correct my answer rather than commenting here? I mean, it would be just easier :)

Comment: Ahh -- that makes sense, as everything passed to `system()` goes through a syntax-parse pass. :)  As for editing things myself, personally, I'd probably just take the bullet about the arbitrary-execution vulnerability out in entirety.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68684/discussion-between-aif-and-charles-duffy).